# Remote access with laptop cover down

Tags: remote-control

Can someone log on to my laptop if the cover is down?
I thought by closing the cover it disconnected the internet.

Answer (score 1):

There are programs that will allow the system to run with the lid closed, but in general putting the lid down will put the system into a sleep state (allowing some internet access for Power Nap if you have that enabled)

Answer (score 0):

If it is disconnected from Internet, than no one can connect to it remotely. There is a setting to wake on Internet access that you can enable or disable.

In your system Preferences Energy you will find the setting for Wake for WiFi access.

To prevent any unauthorized access make sure all Sharing is disabled in your sys pref sharing.

Closing the Lid does not shut down the computer. It goes in Sleep/Hibernate modes. It will perform some maintenance and access Internet if it has to, but that is only from your site, not from outside.